# SslContext getInstance() is not finding the native openssl implementation

Tags: java, openssl, netty

I am trying to optimize TLS encrypted data transfer by using the native instead of Java implementation, as suggested by Netty.  To simplify things, I have deployed using the "uber" static-boringssl jar, as described here:

https://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html#how-to-download-netty-tcnative-boringssl-uber-jar

Our code loads the SslContext by doing SSLContext.getInstance().  Without specifying a Provider, it always finds the Java implementation, but specifying SslProvider.OPENSSL results in

```
java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: OPENSSL
```

The following is a small repository with a simple demonstration of the problem.  The included example output is from running on SL 7.9.  An rpm query demonstrates the presence of the openssl libraries on the node.  The test code also prints out all Netty jars on the classpath prior to running, and as can be seen, the static-boringssl jar is there.

https://github.com/alrossi/netty-tls-test

I imagine that I am overlooking something simple or obvious here, but would be very appreciative of any help you can provide.

Al

Answer (score 2):

These docs are out-dated. Just specify the `SslProvider.OPENSSL` when building the `SslContext`:

```
SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(cert, key)
        .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
        .build();
```

That said as soon as its on your class-path it should also be used by default.

Comment: OMG.  javax.net.ssl.SSLContext vs. io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.  That went right by me.  Thank you.

Comment: or use, still the library in the classpath:  
  
``` java
    SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(cert, key)
           .sslProvider(SslContext.defaultClientProvider() // for c lient
                            SslContext.defaultServerProvider() // for server
                          )
           .build();
```